# asp.net, mvc: How to share the same dropdown list in multple cshtml files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following used in multiple cshtml files:

```
@{
    var grades = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = "--- Select your grade level ---", Value = "", Disabled= true},

        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "K", Value = "K"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "1", Value = "1st"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "2", Value = "2nd"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "3", Value = "3rd"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "4", Value = "4th"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "5", Value = "5th"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "6", Value = "6th"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "7", Value = "7th"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "8", Value = "8th"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "9", Value = "9th"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "10", Value = "10th"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "11", Value = "11th"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "12", Value = "12th"},
    };
}
```

What is the better way to reuse such data instead of copying/pasting in multiple files?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is static data, then just create a static helper class.

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> GetGradeLevels()
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Selected = true, 
                Text = "--- Select your grade level ---", 
                Value = "", Disabled= true},

            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "K", Value = "K"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "1", Value = "1st"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "2", Value = "2nd"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "3", Value = "3rd"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "4", Value = "4th"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "5", Value = "5th"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "6", Value = "6th"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "7", Value = "7th"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "8", Value = "8th"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "9", Value = "9th"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "10", Value = "10th"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "11", Value = "11th"},
            new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "12", Value = "12th"}};
    }
}
```

Then in your cshtml, just:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Whatever, Helper.GetGradeLevels())
```